# How to determine type of ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this method

```
def get_list(limit = nil, page = nil)
  coll = all
  coll = (block_given?) ? (yield coll) : coll
  rowcnt = coll.count
  pages = (limit && limit > 0) ? (rowcnt.to_f/limit).ceil : 1
  coll = coll.limit(limit) if limit && limit > 0
  coll = coll.offset((page-1)*limit) if limit && limit > 0 && page && page > 1
  ret = { rows: coll.all.to_a, rowcnt: rowcnt, page: page || 1, pages: pages, limit: limit || 0 }
  def ret.serialize(include = nil)
    self[:rows].collect! do |row|
      hash = include ? (row.serializable_hash(include: include.incllist)) : row.serializable_hash
      (hash['code'] && hash['code'].end_with?('(TR)')) ? nil : ((block_given?) ? yield(hash,row) : hash)

    end
    self[:rows].compact!
    return self.rest_success,true,self
  end
  return ret
end
```

which I am calling with

```
Unit.get_list() do |q|
# some logic
end
```

How can I determine the type of `coll` in `get_list()`?

I tried with `coll.instance_of?(Unit)` and `coll.is_a?(Unit)` as well as with `self.instance_of?(Unit)` and `self.is_a?(Unit)` but all of them returned `false`.

Comment: did you try `coll.klass == Unit` ?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Okay, that worked, thank you. Maybe you want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
coll.klass == Unit
#OR
coll.model == Unit
```

P.S. Updated the answer based on comments. `#method` is not supported now, use `#model` instead.

Comment: method does not work. Please update the answer to use model instead.